# ¿Como corregir error Network is unreachable al enviar correo en cake php 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake, cakephp-3.x

Buenas tardes tengoelsiguiente codigo con el que envio correo y me funciona bien en mi local pero al subirlo al servidor me manda error:

```
2018-11-05 18:36:12 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException] Network is unreachable
Request URL: /presolicitud/enviar-certificado/6/116/parcial
Referer URL: http://redpa.pw/solicitudes/view-certificado/6/116/parcial
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(207): Cake\Network\Socket->connect()
#1 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php(162): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->_connect()
#2 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Email.php(2051): Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Cake\Mailer\Email))
#3 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Mailer.php(252): Cake\Mailer\Email->send()
#4 /home/redpa/public_html/src/Controller/PresolicitudController.php(2484): Cake\Mailer\Mailer->send('certificado_ema...', Array)
#5 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(440): App\Controller\PresolicitudController->enviarCertificado('6', '116', 'parcial')
#6 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(119): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#7 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(93): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\PresolicitudController))
#8 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(78): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#9 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(59): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#11 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#13 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#15 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#17 /home/redpa/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(80): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#18 /home/redpa/public_html/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#19 {main}
```

la configuracion de correo:

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [ 
            'className' => 'Smtp',// The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //localhost
            'port' => 465, //25
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'prueba@gmail.com',  
            'password' => 'v67367367te',  
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),

        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que en el servidor no hay problemas de conectividad, por ejemplo que no haya un firewall que bloquee la conectividad con ese puerto de salida.

Si tienes acceso shell al servidor puedes probar a hacer

`telnet smtp.gmail.com  465`

Y deberías ver algo como esto si el puerto es accesible:

```
Trying 74.125.140.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```